# The cardinality of the set of algebraic integers whose reciprocal has its largest coefficient (with respect to a integral basis) in a given interval.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n$ be an integral basis for a field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. 
Let $\mathbb{Z}_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$. 
For $a = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \omega_i$, we write $\| a \|_{\infty} = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |a_i|$.

What is the cardinality of the set $\{a: a \in \mathbb{Z}_K, M \leq \| a^{-1} \|^{-1} \leq 2M\}$?

In particular, can the cardinality be bounded between $cM^n$ and $C M^n$ for some constants $0<c<C$ depending on $K$?

Note: The cardinality of the set above is the same as that of the set $\{a: 1/a \in \mathbb{Z}_K, M \leq \| a \|^{-1} \leq 2M\}$.

Comment: Why should this set even be finite? If $\omega_1 = 1$ and $\omega_2 = \sqrt{2}$,
 and $a_n = n \omega_1 + \lfloor n/\sqrt{2} \rfloor \omega_2$, then it seems as
though 
 
$$\|a^{-1}_n\|^{-1} = \frac{n^2 - 2  \lfloor n/\sqrt{2} \rfloor^2}{n}$$
 
lies between $1$ and $2$ infinitely often.

Comment: @user687721 Would you post this as an answer? I'd like to accept it and post a second better question.